# Walk tree structure and enumerate all paths

Tags: perl

Could you please help me with the logic here for problem.

I have three files:

#### data.txt

```
mydata1
mydata2
```

#### parent.txt

```
mydata1###parent
mydata2###parent2
```

#### child.txt

```
parent###child1
parent###child2
parent###child3
child1###subchild1
child1###subchild2
child1###subchild3
subchild1###Ssubchild1
subchild1###Ssubchild2
subchild1###Ssubchild3
```

I require a list of all root items together with every child item (any item two or more jumps away from the root) and the path taken to get there. Note that `mydata2` and `parent2` don't appear below because they have no child items.

It would look like this

```
mydata1 === child1 === parent + child1
mydata1 === subchild1 === parent + child1 + subchild1
mydata1 === Ssubchild1 === parent + child1 + subchild1 + Ssubchild1
mydata1 === Ssubchild2 === parent + child1 + subchild1 + Ssubchild2
mydata1 === Ssubchild3 === parent + child1 + subchild1 + Ssubchild3
mydata1 === subchild2 === parent + child1 + subchild2
mydata1 === subchild3 === parent + child1 + subchild3
mydata1 === child2 === parent + child2
mydata1 === child3 === parent + child3
```

I tried this problem with the below logic but did not get the expected solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @host_name = ("mydata1","mydata2");
my %parent_hash;
my %child_hash;

open (parent,"<","parent.txt") or die "could not open\n";
open (child,"<","childs.txt") or die "could not open\n";

for(<parent>)
{
    my @arr = split("###",$_);
    $parent_hash{$arr[0]}{$arr[1]} = 1;
}

for(<child>)
{
    my @arrr = split("###",$_);
    $child_hash{$arrr[0]}{$arrr[1]} = 1;
}

my $parent;

for(@host_name)
{
    my $host = $_; 

    if(exists($parent_hash{$host}))
    {
        for (keys %{$parent_hash{$host}})
        {
            chomp($_);
            $parent = $_;
            print "$host === $parent ==== $parent\n";
            derive($host,$_,$_,$parent);
        }
    }
}


sub derive()
{
    my $host = shift;
    my $group = shift;
    my $string = shift;
    my $parent = shift;




    for (keys %{$child_hash{$group}})
        {
            chomp($_);
            my $temp = $string;
            $string = $string."+".$_;

            if(exists ($child_hash{$_}))
            {
                print "$host === $_ ==== $string\n";
                derive($host,$_,$string,$parent);
            }   
            else
            {
                print "$host === $_ ==== $string\n";
                $string = $temp;    
            }
        }

}
```

and getting the below result not the expected one

```
mydata1 === parent ==== parent  
mydata1 === child1 ==== parent+child1
mydata1 === subchild3 ==== parent+child1+subchild3
mydata1 === subchild2 ==== parent+child1+subchild2
mydata1 === subchild1 ==== parent+child1+subchild1
mydata1 === Ssubchild2 ==== parent+child1+subchild1+Ssubchild2
mydata1 === Ssubchild3 ==== parent+child1+subchild1+Ssubchild3
mydata1 === Ssubchild1 ==== parent+child1+subchild1+Ssubchild1
mydata1 === child2 ==== parent+child1+child2
mydata1 === child3 ==== parent+child1+child3
mydata2 === parent2 ==== parent2
```

Comment: What links these things together? `mydata1 === child1 === parent + child1`

Comment: Please explain some more: What is the specific problem that prevents you calculating the relationships yourself? How much of the Perl have you figured out, and where are you stuck? For example, do you know how to open a file in Perl, do you understand how to parse the rows into separate parts (before and after `###`) etc?

Comment: Hi Neil,

Thanks for the reply , Let me show you my code here.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question as, although the OP has been careless with the question and made no apparent effort to solve it themselves, I consider it to be a difficult problem that involves building a tree structure of the data and traversing it. It's even more difficult to properly verify the original data. This is a common programming problem that I don't think has been dealt with before on Stack Overflow, and I have a solution to post if the question is reopened.

Comment: @luckylokhande: It's always a bad idea to post a question that just says *I have this data and I want this output*. It's like begging on the streets and saying *I have a wife and children and I need £1000*. Many people will see no evidence that you have made any effort of your own, and your question will be ignored or down-voted and closed

Comment: @Borodin: There technically is not a strict requirement to "show work" on SO, but it is a proxy for isolating the actual problem the OP has. The re-wording of the question helps a lot to make it answerable, so it might be the OP's lucky day. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @NeilSlater: It has become a de-facto requirement that the OP should show at least some effort. However I have seen many questions fall foul of that when the solution is so obscure that the OP has no idea where to start. I think it's fair to close a question like this one originally was, as there was no attempt even to explain the requirement. It is only in working with the data that I understood what was required and could improve the wording. I have to admit that I may not have been so generous with my reopen vote if I didn't have an answer waiting!

Comment: Hi @Neil,@Borodin,@fugu : I have submitted my efforts which I have done till now but not getting the actual output. Could you please help me here to get the expected output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution appears to work fine except you are not sorting the children of the tree and you have a line in your loop iterating over the host names that prints out the parents.  Otherwise I don't see any difference between your output.

So the changes would be to remove that print statement and change `for (keys %{$child_hash{$group}})` to `for (sort keys %{$child_hash{$group}})`

But I also went through your whole program and fixed the way you were storing the data to be more natural and explained a bunch of perl features you were using half right.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Rather than explicitly managing parents and children, you can quite literally store the whole tree
# in memory as a tree for more native iteration through it. For initialization you also need a
# global node list so you can do the lookup.
my @host_names;
my %tree;
my %nodes;

# You can use scalar variables ($fh) instead of global names (fh) for filehandles. This means that
# they will automatically close when they go out of scope if they are used in functions or loops and
# will be checked for existance by use strict which is great for me personally because I make
# variable name typos all the time.
open(my $parent,"<","parent.txt") or die "Could not open 'parent.txt' for read: $!";
open(my $child,"<","child.txt") or die "Could not open 'child.txt' for read: $!";

# As an example of that, this do block will read the host file into host_names and then
# automatically close the file once the block has exited.
@host_names = do {
  open(my $host, '<', 'data.txt') or die "Could not open 'data.txt' for read: $!";
  <$host>;
};
chomp(@host_names);

foreach my $host_name (@host_names) {
  $tree{$host_name} = $nodes{$host_name} = {};
}

# In the ultimate confusing thing that you only have to learn once, you actually want to use while
# instead of for to loop through files. Using a for loop will read the whole file into memory, split
# it on newline and then iterate through it.  While loops will read the file one line at a time.  It
# doesn't make a difference here, but if you were reading a 3GB file, you would notice.
while(<$parent>) {
  chomp;
  # You can automatically unpack arrays in perl and the default second argument for split is $_
  my ($parent, $child) = split(/###/);
  die "$parent does not exist" unless exists $nodes{$parent};
  die "$child already defined" if     exists $nodes{$child};
  $nodes{$parent}{$child} = $nodes{$child} = {};
}

# This loop is exactly the same as above now, you could really make the two files the same and see
# no differences (except that I changed split invocations to give you some more information)
while(<$child>) {
  chomp;
  # If you want, you can also specify the maximum number of items split will look to unpack. If it's
  # not specified and perl sees you unpack it immediately, it will default to the number of items in
  # your list plus 1 (in your case 3). It does this because the behavior is the same either way, and
  # it saves work if you have 200 splittable things in your line. We know there will be exactly two
  # items, so we can save it even more work and tell it that.
  my ($parent, $child) = split(/###/, $_, 2);
  die "$parent does not exist" unless exists $nodes{$parent};
  die "$child already defined" if     exists $nodes{$child};
  $nodes{$parent}{$child} = $nodes{$child} = {};
}

# You can specify what you're iterating over in a for/foreach loop (They are synonyms in perl)
# instead of renaming it on the first line of the loop.
foreach my $host (@host_names) {
  walk($tree{$host}, $host);
}

# With our tree now actually being a tree in memory, our 'derive' function can be a true tree walk.
sub walk {
  my ($node, $host, @path) = @_;
  for my $child (sort keys %$node) {
    if (@path > 0) {
      local $" = " + "; # comment to fix stack overflow highlighter "
      print "$host === $child ==== @path + $child\n";
    }
    walk($node->{$child}, $host, @path, $child);
  }
}
```